# Is there anyway to know the progress in sklearn GridSearch

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, data-science

For grid search is always time consuming, so I want to see how much it run now. For example ,it might output

```
paramsXXX processed
paramsYYY processed
...
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To get the progress, you can increase the verbosity in e.g. [sklearn.grid_search.GridSearchCV](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.grid_search.GridSearchCV.html#sklearn.grid_search.GridSearchCV), by adding the parameter `verbose` and giving it some positive value

```
GridSearchCV(..., verbose=1)
```

From the docs

> verbose : integer
>
> Controls the verbosity: the higher, the more
>   messages.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to know how much time GridSearchCV will take, you can run RandomizedSearchCV with n_iter=10 before running GridSearchCV. Let's say RandomizedSearchCV with n_iter=10 took 10s, GridSearchCV with 100 iterations will take almost 100s. This will give you a fairly accurate idea of how much time will GridSearchCV take.

Or even better you can run RandomizedSearchCV with n_iter=half the iterations of GridSearchCV to get almost same results with half the time.